# Vite + Vue3 + VueRouter Dynamic Import Routes Based on File

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I'm trying to implement DDD to Vue, and the structure is as below:

```
src
- App
  - ...
  - router
    - index.ts
- Dashboard
  - ...
  - router
    - index.ts
- ...
```

The idea is for `src/App/router/index.ts` to populate all routes under src//router/index.ts. Below is the content of the main router file

```js
//src/App/router/index.ts

import { createRouter, createWebHistory, type RouteRecordRaw } from "vue-router";

const importedRoutes = import.meta.glob<Object>("@/**/router/index.ts", { import: 'default' });
const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [];

for (const modules in importedRoutes) {
  importedRoutes[modules]().then((route: any) => {
    routes.push(route);
  });
}

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: routes
});

console.log(router.getRoutes());

export default router;
```

And here is the content of `src/Dashboard/router/index.ts`

```js
//src/Dashboard/router/index.ts

import DashboardView from "@/Dashboard/DashboardView.vue";

const routes = {
  name: "dashboard",
  path: "/",
  component: DashboardView,
}

export default routes;
```

The problem I'm facing (I'm still learning on Typescript, please be kind) is that there are no routes generated from though I've pushed the objects into `routes`, and there are no errors thrown as well. The console just have a warning with `[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/"`.

Please show me the way. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've explored myself and found the answer.

`import.meta.glob` returns a `Promise` object, that's why the `routes` was empty, since it has not resolved.

I found that `import.meta.glob` [accepts the parameter `{eager: true}`](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import) so you don't have to deal with `Promise`. So here's the solution:

```js
//src/App/router/index.ts

import {
  createRouter,
  createWebHistory,
  type RouteRecordRaw
} from "vue-router";

const importedRoutes = import.meta.glob<Object>("@/**/router/index.ts", { import: 'default', eager: true });
const routes: Object[] = [];


for (const modules in importedRoutes) {
  // No Promises since it's eager loaded.
  routes.push(importedRoutes[modules]);
}

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: routes as RouteRecordRaw[]
});

export default router;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found an error base on the solution above, it is related to the array not flattening it is still an object. Here is the modified solution.

```
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory, type RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router'

const importedRoutes = import.meta.glob<Object>('@/modules/**/router/index.ts', {
  import: 'default',
  eager: true
})
const routes: Object[] = []

for (const modules in importedRoutes) {
  routes.push(importedRoutes[modules])
}

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: routes.flat() as RouteRecordRaw[]
})

export default router
```

Comment: ```'@/modules/**/router/index.ts'``` this here is based on the depth of the folder structure you are having. for me, I structure my folder as this ```@/modules/module_name/router/index.ts``` the ```**``` is the wild card name of the folder name you are given